# Underline does not work in axlsx in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spreadsheet, underline, axlsx

I am using axlsx gem to generate spreadsheets.

I am using various styles like bold font, borders, background colors etc which all work fine.

But when I use underline style, it does not work at all (I don't get any error though).

```
bold_underline = wb.styles.add_style({:b => true, :u => true})
```

This is the code I am using. Bold works fine but underline does not (but it does not throw any error either).

Please help!